# Can't pass a Python list on command line with zsh as shell

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am trying to add an optional command line argument that takes in a list using argparse. I am currently specifying the argument as follows (note there are other command line arguments as well, but I seem to be having issues with the following one because it is a list as opposed to a single string or number).

```
parser.add_argument("--num_objects", nargs='+', type=int, default=[2, 4, 8],
  help="Number of objects at each time")
```

However, when I try to run the script `python game.py --num_objects=[4, 8, 12]`, I get the error `zsh:1: no matches found: --num_filters=[4, 8, 12]`. How do I fix this?

Comment: That error is produced by the shell, `zsh`.  It doesn't even call python much the parser.  With that `nargs` you want to use 'python game.py --num_objects 4 8 12'.  No comma or brackets, just the numbers separated by spaces.  You might also want to look a `sys.argv` to see what the shell passes to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the list in 'single quotes', to prevent Zsh from interpreting it as a pattern:

```sh
python game.py --num_objects='[4, 8, 12]'
```

Alternatively, you can tell Zsh to not interpret any of the input as patterns:

```sh
noglob python game.py --num_objects=[4, 8, 12]
```

Comment: Correct as far as it goes re: shell usage, incorrect in terms of what argparse expects; see the comment by hpaulj @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64563789/how-to-add-a-list-command-line-argument-using-argparse#comment114163836_64563789